# How to disable store password warning?

Tags: svn

After command:

```
svn --username=test --password=1 co http://1.1.1.1/svn/dev/web/trunk/ ./
```

I see message:

```
ATTENTION!  Your password for authentication realm:
can only be stored to disk unencrypted!
```

How to disable this warning ? I don't want to save password, I want run only this script automatic without any promt ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `%APPDATA%/Subversion/config` file you have two auth-releated parameters

```
# store-passwords = no
# store-auth-creds = no
```

(with default values "yes"). You can:

- uncomment both parameters and doesn't get requests in future (nothing will be stored at all)

or (better, more secure way)

- confirm once storing unencrypted credentials and remove `--username` and `--password` option from command line in order to avoid easy interception of authentication details: cached data will be used (NOTE: **globally** used for any repository on 1.1.1.1 host)

Comment: These settings can now be set in `%APPDATA%/Subversion/servers`.